# this.props in external fetch function is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fetch

I am using React.js for my project. I have a problem with this.props in external fetch function. Here is my code

```
export default function request(method, url, body) {
  console.log(this); //undefined here
  if (method === "GET") {
    body = undefined;
  }
  return fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token
    },
    body
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(this); //undefined here
    if (res.status === 401) {
      this.props.history.push("/login");
      return Promise.reject("Unauthorized.");
    } else {
      return res;
    }
  });
}

export const get = url => request("GET", url);
export const post = (url, body) => request("POST", url, body);
export const put = (url, body) => request("PUT", url, body);
export const del = (url, body) => request("DELETE", url, body);
```

If res.status ===401. I hope my program can jump back to login. However, this.props in my function is always undefined. How I can bind this with specific component?

Comment: you have to pass the history prop to the request function or just catch the unauthorized error and do the redirect on the calling place :)

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be? And how does this relate to React? Why are you accessing `this.props` in the first place? Your function doesn't seem to be a React component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exported functions above are not components, this.props will always be unavailable. If you wanted, you could create an extra argument to accept `this.props` in the function and then supply `this.props` each time you call the functions.

Basically, you would need to write a component, that, upon being called for rendering, triggers the fetch function. As a component you could then take advantage of the `withRouter` function from `react-router` or `react-router-dom`. Then use:

```
export default withRouter(component-name)
```

So, any time this component is called, `this.props.history` becomes available, just as other props. You might as well pass any other props on the JSX tag.

Here is how it should look like:

```
class TryComponent extends Component {

    myFetchFunction() {
        //this.props.history is available
        //call request, get, delete... function here and pass props
    }

    render() {
        // call here or call from the constructor
        this.myFetchFunction();

        return <AnyJSX></AnyJSX>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(TryComponent);
```

So when you write `<TryComponent foo="bar" />`, foo is available as a props and history is also available as a props.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not trying to do anything react-ish within your external request() function.

Instead, right now your request() function is returning something, therefore wherever it is called (in a react component most likely) you will be able to chain .then() onto it.

So within the react component where it is being used:

```
import { get } from '...'

ReactComponent extends Component {

  classMethodToMakeRequest() {
    get('someurl.com').then(() => this.props.history.push('/push/route'))
  }

}
```

You will only have access to `this.props` from within a react component.